# undefined group option when using branch reset group regex in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm working with Ruby and I have a regex to match a pattern:

`REGEX = /(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|(.*))/`  (https://regex101.com/r/t2jXuu/1)

It works very well as I can test with regex101, but when I run the Ruby code, I face:

`undefined group option: /(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|(.*))/ (SyntaxError)`

What does it mean and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You can use https://rubular.com It gives same error as like Ruby code. Test here, if it works, then it will work in Ruby code too.